# Tag synonym: datacentre -> datacenter

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

"Two countries separated by a common language", indeed...

Comment: To be fair, the meta sites have the same filters as the parent sites, and if a question was asked with only 8 words in it would rightly fail ;)

Comment: Sure, sure... punish concision in questions... <grin>

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that I'm the curlprit of creating [datacentre](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/datacentre), and it was only used once ;)

Doesn't make me feel any less dirty about marking this as [status-completed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) though.